# Returning `std::string_view` not include first character

Tags: c++, c++17

If I have the following two functions:

```
std::string tolower(std::string s)
{
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
        [](unsigned char c) { return static_cast<unsigned char>(std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))); });

    return s;
}

std::string_view tolower2(std::string s)
{
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
        [](unsigned char c) { return static_cast<unsigned char>(std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))); });

    return s;
}
```

The only difference are their return values.

The results of these functions are:

```
// returns "test" - expected
std::cout << tolower("TeSt") << std::endl;

// returns " est" - not expected
std::cout << tolower2("TeSt") << std::endl;
```

Why is there a difference?

Comment: I think: The returned `std::string_view` is view into the buffer managed by `std::string s` which will get destroyed before `tolower2` returns so we have UB.  Not 100% sure when the temporary created for the parameter `std::string s` gets destroyed so not posting as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because, in the first example, you are just returning and using a string (nice and safe).

And in the second example, you are potentially *(see below)* returning a view over a local string that no longer exists, so the view is "dangling" and your program has undefined behaviour.

Apparently, in your case, some part of the function return machinery and/or the string destruction machinery has overwritten the first character of what used to be the string buffer.

---

> [`[expr.call/7]:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#7) *[..]* It is implementation-defined whether the lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns or at the end of the enclosing full-expression. *[..]*

Comment: Thanks for the reference - that's what was causing me to stop and think.

Comment: @RichardCritten Only thing is I haven't verified how long that wording's been there but I think the issue is clear enough for our purposes here

Comment: It is pretty old.  It permits function argument cleanup to occur in either the called or calling context; basically two different ABIs.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont See, that's interesting, because the next sentence is _"The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the calling function."_